# How to implement fuzzy minimum function via fuzzy maximum

Tags: math, min, fuzzy-logic

I know that I can represent fuzzy max via power function(i need it in neural network) i.e.

> def max(p:Double)(a:Double,b:Double) =
>   pow(pow(a,p) + pow(b,p) , 1/p)
>   // assumption a >=0 and b >=0

It is become maximum when p -> infinity and sum when p = 1

Not sure how correctly implement fuzzy minimum.

Comment: What do you want the min function to be for p=1 and p=∞?  Or do you want different critical values for p in the min function?

Comment: I want same behavior as my fuzzy max. I.e. it should lie between (a+b) if p=1 and min(a,b) if p=inf and continues over p

Comment: This is more of a math question than a programming question.  Try http://math.stackexchange.com/.

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to replace "sum" with "harmonic sum" for the p=1 case, you can use

1/(pow(pow(a,-p) + pow(b,-p),1/p))

This converges to min(a,b) as p goes to infinity.

For p=1 it's 1/(1/a + 1/b), which is related to the harmonic mean but without the factor of 2. Just like in your original formula, a+b is related to the arithmetic mean but without the factor of 2.

However, note that both of these formulas (yours and mine) converge much more slowly to the limit as p goes to infinity, for cases where a and b are closer together.

Comment: This is really cool. However I need something above min(a,b) for p<inf. The problem I want intersection between sets, but with min it is too small. I probably will use linear combination min(a,b)*p+(a+b)*(1-p)

Comment: Out of curiosity, is your original power parameter p a value that is tweaked to get good performance on your data sets with the neural network and then kept fixed? Or does p change over multiple iterations to enforce convergence?

Comment: I plan to train nn with different p and then select best p.